# 29:52: Error: Property 'photoURL' cannot be accessed on 'User?' because it is potentially null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I am trying to add google sign in with firebase auth in my basic flutter app, but I am getting above mentioned error. I searched alot but couldn't found any answer, please help me out. This is the whole error in my terminal:

```
lib/logged_in_widget.dart:29:52: Error: Property 'photoURL' cannot be accessed on 'User?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'User' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-1.4.1/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),
                                                   ^^^^^^^^
lib/logged_in_widget.dart:34:32: Error: Property 'displayName' cannot be accessed on 'User?' because it is potentially null.
 - 'User' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('../../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-1.4.1/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
                'Name:' + user.displayName!,
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 21s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have done null safety too using:

```
dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety
```

This is the main code:

```
import 'package:yt_firebase2/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LoggedInWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // final FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Logged In'),
          centerTitle: true,
          actions: [
            TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('Logout'),)
          ],
        ),
        body: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          color: Colors.blueGrey.shade900,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('profile', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),),
              SizedBox(height: 32,),
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 40,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),

              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8,),
              Text(
                'Name:' + user.displayName!,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the code in my firebase_auth file:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class GoogleSignInProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
  final googleSign = GoogleSignIn();

  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;

  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;

  Future GoogleLogin() async {
    final googleUser = await googleSign.signIn();
    if (googleUser == null) return;
    _user = googleUser;

    final googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

    final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and this is my pubspec.yaml file"

```
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  firebase_auth: ^1.1.4
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.0.0
  provider: ^5.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: You should really read and understand dart null safety. The solution to your warnings is **not** to just put `!` whenever a warning pops up.

Comment: Even I remove ```!```, it shows the same error with another error: ```The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just as a side note:**

```
  GoogleSignInAccount? _user;
  GoogleSignInAccount get user => _user!;
```

This is really not a great practice if you are not 100% certain that _user will never be null. But getting _user can got wrong, without returning any value.

**To your question:**

`NetworkImage()` requires a `String` (**non-nullable type**)! In your  code `NetworkImage(user.photoURL!),` you are doing that by telling dart that it logically can never be null by using the bang operator (!).

The same is the case for `displayName`, since `Text()` also `requires a String` not a String? --> **That is the whole point of nullsafety: To avoid null errors during run time.**

**Solution:**
Make sure `GoogleSignInAccount? _user`; is not null before referencing it anywhere
in your code.